# Sidekiq workers.size != process.size

Tags: ruby-on-rails, concurrency, sidekiq

Can someone describe me how sidekiq workers relate to pids in OS?
I have ubuntu 14.04 on aws and I configured my QA environment in `sidekiq.yml` to use 2 workers. As it shown [here](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Advanced-Options#the-sidekiq-configuration-file).

But what I see in my OS is next:
[image]

So 2 workers equals 6 processes. But is correct. How do I limit processes for sidekiq? Or what should I do to reduce memory usage.
Sometimes my server runs out of memory. So shutdown occurs.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you read the docs? https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Problems-and-Troubleshooting#memory-bloat

Comment: @MikePerham, I didn't see this page. Thanks for pointing me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are threads in the htop listing, not processes.

Comment: Is there any formula how threads and workers relate? Or should I even bother about many threads created?

Comment: Two of those threads are your workers, four are internal Sidekiq threads that you shouldn't care about.

Comment: There's no formula, the count is an impl detail.